# How to replace all linefeeds in a quote string use regular expression?

Tags: python, regex

How can I replace all the `"\n"` that appear within double quotes but not the ones that don't?

```
origin = 'some text alt="description\n description\n description" \n other text'
```

I have tried to solve it in python like this, but I found I can't determine the count of "\n" in this pattern.

```
re.sub(r'(alt=".*)\n(.*)"', r'\1\2', origin)
```

Comment: There is a "\n" not in quote string, I have to keep it.

Comment: Can you tell us what you tried, what you were expecting it to do, and what it actually did do?

Comment: Do you need to support escaped quotes?

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 I want to replace "\n" in a  img tag in a html string.

Comment: And what did your above attempt actually do?

Comment: It can only replace one, but I can't determine the count of "\n" in this pattern.

Comment: If your `origin` string is the result of processing some actual HTML, you will have significantly better luck doing your parsing using something like BeautifulSoup or lxml rather than using regexes. (But if you have just been handed this `origin` string, you'd have to construct some semi-valid HTML around it to run it through BS/lxml, which is probably not worth the trouble.)

Comment: Try https://regex101.com/r/iZ1uZ0/2

Comment: @SIslam Does this replace all `\n` if there is a `"` after the `\n`

Comment: @ shellfly it removes all `\n` inside `"` BTW what do you mean?

Comment: @SIslam 'some text \nalt="description\n description\n description" \n other text', all the `\n` except for the last one will be matched

Answer (score 1):

You should do it in two passes. It would be simpler and more readable because too clever regexes can be hard to maintain.

First get the string(s) inside double quote

```
qstrings = re.findall('"(.*?)"', origin, re.DOTALL)
```

You have then simple strings to process:

```
for string in strings:
    filtered_string = string.replace('\n', replacement_char)
    # process filtered_string
```

Answer (score 0):

Combine the fact that `re.sub` can use a function for the replacement argument with `str.replace`:

```
>>> re.sub(r'alt="[^"]*"', lambda x: x.group(0).replace('\n', ''), origin)
'some text alt="description description description" \n other text'
```

This looks for `alt="any number of any characters except a double quote"` and replaces it with `alt="the matched string but with newlines removed via str.replace"`.

You could also use a more generic `.*?` instead of the `[^"]*` if you add the `re.DOTALL` flag, which makes `.` includes the newline character:

```
>>> re.sub(r'alt=".*?"', lambda x: x.group(0).replace('\n', ''), origin, flags=re.DOTALL)
'some text alt="description description description" \n other text'
```

The `?` is so that it stops at the first closing quote rather than going all the way to the last closing quote, which would be important for strings with more than one `alt="...` like `alt="a \n b" c \n d alt="e \n f"`.